# How to resolve the MySQL's .MYI file corrupted issue without restart the database server?

Tags: mysql, myisam, corrupt

One of my MYSQL database table has corrupted. And when I perform check table, optimize table operation, the following error messages occurred:

- Key in wrong position at page 3512320
- Can't read key block from filepos: 6256640
- Incorrect key file for table
- The indexes PRIMARY and ATYPE_NAME_IDX seem to be equal and one of
  them could possibly be removed
- Operation failed

I tried below tasks to resolve this:

1. I use repair option, its works fine.
2. I did check table or optimize table operation after repair , again
   the same error message coming.
3. Exported the data dump and imported into new database, after
   sometime the same error comes for particular table.

I found .MYI has corrupted.

Since my sites are working under shared sever, I am not able to stop or start the server.

Is it possible to resolve this issue without stop and start database server?

Comment: If `REPAIR` works fine, then what's the issue after that?

Comment: The REPAIR works fine for some time only after then again it gives the same error. That's why I look for permanent solution for this issue.

Comment: Advise your host. I would suspect an imminent hard disk failure. Is it always on the same table, and on this table only?

Answer (score 4):

Make a backup of the .MYI file and re-create it.

```
# recover missing *.MYI file
mysqlcheck --user=USER --password=PWD --repair --use-frm DATABASE TABLE
```

It is possible to do this without restart.